# How to round float in Bash? (to a decimal)

Tags: bash

I want to round my float variables in order for the sum of these variables to be equal 1. Here is my program :

```
for float in 0.0 0.001 0.01 0.025 0.05 0.075 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.225 0.25; do
w1=`echo "1.0 - $float" | bc -l`   
w2=`echo "$w1/3" | bc -l`
echo "$w2 0.0 $w2 0.0 0.0 0.0 $w2 $float 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0"
done
```

Where the sum `3*$w2 + $float` has to be 1.00.
I'm a beginner but I need this to compute some results.

I tried already what I found on the internet to round `w2`, but I didn't manage to make it work. And it has to be rounded and not truncated for the final result to be 1.00.

Comment: With a probability of 2/3 you can't have three times the same `w2` so that the sum is 1. If you really need to enforce the sum to be 1, you have two options: alter one of the `w2`'s or alter the `float`. You should specify which behavior you want, and in case of alteration of the `w2`'s, which one you want to alter (first, second or third, or random).

Comment: Hum, nice approach, i will try alter the float, because the 3 w2 have to be the same exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bc` lets you use variables, so you can say:

```
for float in 0.0 0.001 0.01 0.025 0.05 0.075 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.225 0.25; do 
    { read w2; read f; } < <(
        bc -l <<< "scale=5; w2=(1.0-$float)/3; w2; 1.0-3*w2"
    )
    echo "$w2 0.0 $w2 0.0 0.0 0.0 $w2 $f 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0"
done
```

```
.33333 0.0 .33333 0.0 0.0 0.0 .33333 .00001 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.33300 0.0 .33300 0.0 0.0 0.0 .33300 .00100 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.33000 0.0 .33000 0.0 0.0 0.0 .33000 .01000 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.32500 0.0 .32500 0.0 0.0 0.0 .32500 .02500 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.31666 0.0 .31666 0.0 0.0 0.0 .31666 .05002 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.30833 0.0 .30833 0.0 0.0 0.0 .30833 .07501 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.30000 0.0 .30000 0.0 0.0 0.0 .30000 .10000 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.29166 0.0 .29166 0.0 0.0 0.0 .29166 .12502 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.28333 0.0 .28333 0.0 0.0 0.0 .28333 .15001 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.27500 0.0 .27500 0.0 0.0 0.0 .27500 .17500 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.26666 0.0 .26666 0.0 0.0 0.0 .26666 .20002 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.25833 0.0 .25833 0.0 0.0 0.0 .25833 .22501 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.25000 0.0 .25000 0.0 0.0 0.0 .25000 .25000 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Adjust `scale=?` as required.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment in your OP you say it's acceptable to alter the `float` variable so as to have a sum equal to 1. In this, case, first compute the `w2` and then re-compute float from that:

```
w2=$(bc -l <<< "(1-($float))/3")
float=$(bc -l <<< "1-3*($w2)")
```

The whole thing, written in a better style:

```
floats=( 0.0 0.001 0.01 0.025 0.05 0.075 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.225 0.25 )
for float in "${floats[@]}"; do
    w2=$(bc -l <<< "(1-($float))/3")
    float=$(bc -l <<< "1-3*($w2)")
    printf "%s 0.0 %s 0.0 0.0 0.0 %s %s 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0\n" "$w2" "$w2" "$w2" "$float"
done
```

This uses the precision provided by `bc -l` (20 decimal digits after the decimal point). If you don't want that accuracy, you may round the `w2` before recomputing `float` as so:

```
floats=( 0.0 0.001 0.01 0.025 0.05 0.075 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.225 0.25 )
for float in "${floats[@]}"; do
    w2=$(bc -l <<< "scale=3; (1-($float))/3")
    float=$(bc <<< "1-3*($w2)")
    printf "%s 0.0 %s 0.0 0.0 0.0 %s %s 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0\n" "$w2" "$w2" "$w2" "$float"
done
```

Note that the last `bc` isn't called with the `-l` option: it will use whatever significant digits are in `w2`. Change the `scale` to suit your needs. Proceeding thus will guarantee that your numbers add up to 1, as you can check from the output of the previous snippet:

```
.333 0.0 .333 0.0 0.0 0.0 .333 .001 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.333 0.0 .333 0.0 0.0 0.0 .333 .001 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.330 0.0 .330 0.0 0.0 0.0 .330 .010 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.325 0.0 .325 0.0 0.0 0.0 .325 .025 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.316 0.0 .316 0.0 0.0 0.0 .316 .052 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.308 0.0 .308 0.0 0.0 0.0 .308 .076 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.300 0.0 .300 0.0 0.0 0.0 .300 .100 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.291 0.0 .291 0.0 0.0 0.0 .291 .127 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.283 0.0 .283 0.0 0.0 0.0 .283 .151 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.275 0.0 .275 0.0 0.0 0.0 .275 .175 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.266 0.0 .266 0.0 0.0 0.0 .266 .202 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.258 0.0 .258 0.0 0.0 0.0 .258 .226 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
.250 0.0 .250 0.0 0.0 0.0 .250 .250 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I see I have a lot of work in bash to progress... !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `bc` utility to process floating point numbers in bash.

For example consider the code given below,

```
a=15
b=2
echo "$a / $b"
```

will give you **7**  as result.

Where as,

```
a=15
b=2
echo "$a / $b" | bc -l
```

Will give **7.500000** as results

Comment: And how to have 7.50 only then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` to round the output of `bc`:

```
printf '%.2f\n' $( bc -l <<< "3 * $w2 + $float" )
```

Comment: I have an error when I use your line : line 4: printf: .99999999999999999999: no valable number. I don't know, it works on your shell?

Comment: I use exactly the same line... ! I'm getting crazy ^^

Comment: @user3589400: What's your bash version? Mine is 3.00.15(1)

Comment: I don't know the command to know what is my bash version, can you tell me? Thank you.