# How can I convert from a decimal to an integral numeric variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, integer

I have a value which looks like this: 26.3

I want to work on that value but I need it to be integer, so is there a simple way to do that?

```
26.3 -> 26
44.9 -> 44
```

Thanks

Comment: At least write the reason for voting down...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round float in Bash? (to a decimal)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389258/how-to-round-float-in-bash-to-a-decimal). Check also  [rounding up float in bash to a decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465496/rounding-up-float-point-numbers-bash) and [how to round floating point numbers in shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167058/how-to-round-floating-point-numbers-in-shell)

Comment: you are 'flooring' ie always rounding down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use awk:

```
$ var=26.3
$ awk -v v="$var" 'BEGIN{printf "%d", v}'
26
```

The `%d` format specifier results in only the integer part of the number being printed, rounding it down.

As Mark has mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27357056/2088135), a simple substitution will fail in cases where there is no leading digit, such as `.9`, whereas this approach will print `0`.

Rather than using a format specifier, it is also possible to use the `int` function in awk. The variable can be passed in on standard input rather than defining a variable to make things shorter:

```
$ awk '{$0=int($0)}1' <<< "44.9"
44
```

In case you're not familiar with awk, the `1` at the end is common shorthand, which always evaluates to true so awk performs the default action, which is to print the line. `$0` is a variable which refers to the contents of the line.

Thanks to [Jidder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3442743/jidder) for the suggestion.

Comment: Other ways, `awk '$0=int($0)' <<< "26.3"` or if it can be 0, `'{$0=int($0)}1'` or using a variable `awk -v v="$var" 'BEGIN{print int(v)}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a substitution to replace a dot and anything following it:

```
v=26.3
s=${v/\.*/}
echo $s
26
```

It truncates rather than deciding which direction to round... it might have fun with `.63` though :-( whereas `0.63` will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `bc` to do the ceiling to previous int:

```
n='26.3'
bc <<< "$n/1"
26

n='26.6'
bc <<< "$n/1"
26
```

Comment: It looks like the OP doesn't actually want to round the number to the nearest integer.

Comment: I would call the "ceiling to previous int" the "floor".

Comment: lol :) true `floor` is indeed the operation being performed here.

Comment: Nope, it's not the `floor()` because `floor(-2.7)` is `-3` and your function gives `-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to just want to drop the fractional part:

```
x=26.3
x=${x%.*}
```

This is handled in the shell without needing to run any external programs.